# Having issues seeing GLASS in Fastboot

Tags: google-glass, fastboot

I can see my GLASS id in adb and adb reboot-bootloader seems to work.  I can not see my device id in fastboot however and fastboot oem unlock hangs on "waiting for device". Pressing the camera button does reboot the device.

Has anyone else had / seen this issue and what have you done to remedy?

I am currently on XE7 with debugging on. I have side-loaded apk's before with no issue via adb. I would like to know of any possible solutions to be able to see my GLASS in fastboot.

*My Solution-*
**I had issues on Win 8 so I swapped over to my OS X install, unplugged all usb peripherals  and then ran "./adb reboot bootloader", saw my GLASS in "./fastboot devices" and then ran "./fastboot oem unlock" twice to initiate.**

I did not try unplugging all peripherals in win 8.  That may help for those that have the same issue on Win 8.

Comment: Did you ever get it to work on Win8 x64?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a hardware technique to get your Glass into fastboot. Make sure your device has some charge (15% or more should be sufficient) and follow these steps.

1. Power down your device by holding the power button for 15 seconds.
2. Press and hold the camera button. Keep holding it until step 5.
3. Briefly press the power button.
4. Wait until the LED solidly illuminates.
5. Release the camera button.

Now your device should be visible to fastboot. Plug it into a USB port and use fastboot to list devices:

```
$ fastboot devices
```

If your device is listed, you can now run other fastboot commands.

Comment: Did all above but when I type `$ fastboot devices` nothing shows up. If I type `$ adb devices`, I can see the glass. When I type `$ adb reboot bootloader`, my ADB device driver dissapears in device manager and another unknown device appears as 'notle'. What am I supposed to do? BTW glass runs XE9 and I'm on Win8 x64.

Comment: I can get into fastboot via the instructions (the light blinks, not pulses), but GLASS restarts into normal mode the second I plug in the USB cable. Win7 XE19.1 `adb reboot bootloader` causes a normal restart, not into fastboot also. So stuck...

Answer (score 2):

This issue on OS X,  https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=243  is still not addressed (please star the issue while there), it still exists post XE8 regardless of how you start fastboot which as noted, times out and will reboot after inactivity of just a few seconds. Part of the problem is that the USB vendorId switches between Google and TI when switching between adb and fastboot (bootloader) modes.

The solution for Windows:

In android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver\android_winusb.inf

Add to both the [Google.NTamd64] and [Google.NTx86] sections 2 additional lines:

```
;Google Glass
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_9001
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_9001&MI_01
%SingleBootLoaderInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_9002
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_9002&REV_0100
```

Then from ControlPanel->System->Device Manager confirm the VID and PID values with the yellow warning tagged device or “unknown device” - if not the same, edit to match these values.

Comment: I did all Jenny mentioned but when I type `$ fastboot devices` nothing shows up. If I type `$ adb devices`, I can see the glass. When I type `$ adb reboot bootloader`, my ADB device driver dissapears in device manager and another unknown device appears as 'notle'. What am I supposed to do? BTW glass runs XE9 and I'm on Win8 x64.

Comment: adb reboot-bootloader