# fastboot problems leads to bootable but non-starting glass

Tags: google-glass, fastboot

I was hoping to have some Glass hacking fun tonight.  Turned out really bad.  :(

Let me try to explain the steps I have taken.

1. I installed Launcher.apk and Setting.apk
2. Paired a keyboard and mouse
3. All was good.

Then I tried to unlock the device as described at https://developers.google.com/glass/downloads/system

1. adb reboot bootloader
2. fastboot oem unlock

The system sat there for over an hour so I hit Ctrl+c assuming that something had gone wrong.  I checked if the system was in adb or fastboot mode and it looked like it was still in fastboot, so I tried again.  30 minutes later nothing had happened so I Ctrl+c'd it again.

Here is a copy of the output of the terminal for those steps:

```
local:Downloads mmicire$ adb install -r Launcher2.apk 
4361 KB/s (9723188 bytes in 2.176s)
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/Launcher2.apk
Success
local:Downloads mmicire$ adb install -r Settings.apk 
3937 KB/s (3269290 bytes in 0.810s)
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/Settings.apk
Success
local:Downloads mmicire$ adb devices
List of devices attached 
015D98410D020013    device

local:Downloads mmicire$ adb reboot bootloader
local:Downloads mmicire$ fastboot oem unlock
...
(bootloader) Warning: Unlocking your device will void your warranty
(bootloader) and erase your personal data from the device.
(bootloader) Run "fastboot oem unlock" again to confirm.
(bootloader) Device still locked.
OKAY [  0.001s]
finished. total time: 0.001s
local:Downloads mmicire$ fastboot oem unlock
...
^C
local:Downloads mmicire$ adb reboot bootloader
error: device not found
local:Downloads mmicire$ fastboot devices
015D98410D020013    fastboot
local:Downloads mmicire$ fastboot oem unlock
...
^C
local:Downloads mmicire$ fastboot reboot
rebooting...
```

After the device rebooted it went back into the Glass home screen and everything looked fine.  So I tried adb reboot bootloader again and the system seemed unable to boot into fastboot mode.  When I type "adb reboot bootloader" the system shutdown, rebooted, showed the GLASS logo and started right back up into Android.

I then tried Jenny Murphy's solution for fastboot here -- [Having issues seeing GLASS in Fastboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17519865/having-issues-seeing-glass-in-fastboot) -- and it did not change the situation.  The system boots, the LED comes on solid for about 5 seconds, then the system reboots and I see the GLASS logo as the system is coming up.

So I thought that possibly doing a factory reset might fix things.  (It was a stretch at this point.)   I went into the Glass setting and performed a factory reset.

The system rebooted, presented the GLASS logo, and then presents the welcome screen asking me to go to google.com/myglass.  I went to the URL on my laptop and configured a WIFI connection.  The Glass does not seem to be reading QR codes at this point.  I have a very clear picture of the QR code and it just does not seem to be responding at all.

The problem I have now is that I have no way of getting past the second screen for WIFI, I can't turn on debugging since I can't get to the settings menu, and I also can't hardware-enable fastboot to reset the image to factory.  :(

So, after a discouraging evening of hacking, I am needing some help.  At this point, the Glass can only boot, ask me to go to the web, and then pretend to read QR codes to no avail.  Feeling like a d-bag for pseudo-bricking a 48-hour old Glass.

Thoughts anyone?

This was on a OSX 10.8.5 machine running adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130917.  I do have linux machines available if that helps.

Thank you ahead of time.

---

EDIT:  I have been able to log back into the device and enable debugging.  "adb reboot bootloader" still gives the previous behavior of shutting down, LED is solid for about 5 seconds, reboot, GLASS screen.   I do see a usb device in linux appear and then disappear during what I assume is the fastboot debug device coming up and down during this cycle.

---

EDIT:  Tried it on my linux box as recommended by Jenny, but no dice.  The Glass is not willing to stay in fastboot mode.  On reboot, while watching dmesg, I can see the Android debug device dissapear, the glass reboots, I see the fastboot device come up and then three seconds later it dissapears.  Then the Glass reboots into normal Android.

:(

---

SOLUTION:  (And this makes *NO* sense to me.)  I basically ran the battery completely dead.  I have had other Android phones where I needed to pull the batteries and let them sit for a while, so I tried the closest thing that I could accomplish without disassembling the battery from the unit.  It sat on my desk completely drained for a couple days.  I would turn the Glass on even after dying to drain the battery as far as possible.  Frankly, this was as much out of frustration as anything else.

72 hours later, I charged it for about 30 minutes and plugged it into my Linux machine and did the following:

```
mmicire@blue:~$ sudo fastboot devices
015D98410D020013    fastboot
mmicire@blue:~$ sudo fastboot oem unlock
...
(bootloader) Warning: Unlocking your device will void your warranty
(bootloader) and erase your personal data from the device.
(bootloader) Run "fastboot oem unlock" again to confirm.
(bootloader) Device still locked.
OKAY [  0.001s]
finished. total time: 0.001s
mmicire@blue:~$ sudo fastboot oem unlock
...
(bootloader) Erasing personal data. This could take a while...
(bootloader) Erasing cache...
(bootloader) Erasing userdata...
(bootloader) Unlocking...
(bootloader) Device unlocked!
OKAY [256.353s]
finished. total time: 256.353s
```

Nothing done differently from the last test for Jenny.  Not sure what I did, but it just decided to work.  I suppose there was something resident with the charged battery?

Thank you to everyone that helped.  I hope that this helps someone else.  Off to hacking....

Comment: You need to go into Device Info in MyGlass, and then click Factory Reset. You reset from Glass, but MyGlass doesn't know it. The problem you're having is that you're scanning the WiFI QR Code, but you need the setup one, so to solve it do the factory reset.

Comment: Yep.. did it on both ends.  On the MyGlass side it says at the top of the screen `Your reset has been requested and will be processed as soon as the device is available.'  I am assuming that the device needs to connect to become available.

Comment: Hmm. That seems like a problem because Glass can't connect to the web. Maybe ask the Glass Guides?

Comment: If you want, you can also post this on the Glass Explorers community.

Comment: Ok!  Thank you for the hint.  Apparently after doing the factory reset option in MyGlass you have to go back into the Setup link at the top of the screen.  My fault for not realizing that.  I am logged in at this point and will see if I can get any further.  Thank you for getting me past that point.

Comment: Someone said, "Select the Setup tab and go through the initial WiFi network setup there.  Everything then works ok." This would be on the MyGlass website. Looks like I'm a little late. But always great to help a fellow Glass user out!

Comment: It sounds like Glass is working now, just that you're not able to root it. If you'd like to take another swing with fastboot, can you try from your linux machine?

Comment: Thank you Jenny.  I will try with my linux machine this weekend.

Comment: No dice.   The Glass won't actually stay in fastboot mode long enough for the utility to see it.   Through dmesg, I can see the USB device disappear on reboot, go into fastboot, dissapear again, and then boot back up into normal mode.  :(    Not sure what to do at this point.

Answer (score 1):

While not identical, I had a similar issue when trying to upgrade to XE10.  It would reboot but would never leave the Glass startup screen, then after rebooting again it seemed to run properly but I couldn't upgrade and had other issues.

What I ended up having to do was re-install from the factory image (provided on the same screen as the root boot image).

Good instructions on doing a fresh install of the factory image here: http://www.glassxe.com/2013/05/28/how-to-unlock-root-and-reset-glass-using-factory-images/

Comment: Tim -- thank you for the comment.  I wish that I could get it back to a factory condition at this point.  The problem is that I cannot get into fastboot mode, so the suggestions on that page fail around step 3 after I do the "adb reboot-bootloader".    I have a lot of experience rooting and doing custom firmware on other phones.  I have never seen anything refuse to go into fastboot before.  :(   Regardless, thank you for the input.  Really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem, looks like you've fixed it from your edited post.  Nice!