# Hardware Fastboot Boot Method in XE11 not working?

Tags: google-glass

I got stuck on my Glass unit with Launchy crashing (sideloaded the wrong version -_-) in XE11 every time I try to launch an application, including the built-in settings. The problem is for some reason I don't have ADB access anymore and because of Launchy, now can't even reenable Debug mode.

So I am now trying to boot into fastboot mode using the hardware method reference here: [Having issues seeing GLASS in Fastboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17519865/having-issues-seeing-glass-in-fastboot)

But when I keep the camera button pressed and press the power button briefly, the LED is solid for a few seconds and then goes on to blink at very low frequency. No matter how long I seem to keep the camera button pressed, the LED never goes solid.

I've also tried to plug in the unit to my computer and look for it show up in the System Information (the Apple Device Manager equivalent).

Does anyone know if the fastboot hardware method changed in XE11? Or what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Charles.

Comment: Hmm, after fiddling with it a number of times, it seems that I was holding the camera button for too long when booting.
I was eventually able to see a response when doing `fastboot devices`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slow blink you're seeing is Glass in fastboot. Once in fastboot you can verify that it's connected by doing a device list:

```
$ fastboot devices
```

If you see output, you'll be able to run other fastboot commands.