# Google Glass not in Fastboot devices

Tags: android, google-glass, fastboot

I've been trying to root my new pair of Glass using fastboot oem unlock. I know I've done it before and it worked fine however I did a factory reset causing me to root it again.
Whenever I do

```
adb reboot-bootloader
```

it reboots the device however I can see it when I do

```
adb devices
```

NOT

```
fastboot devices
```

it hangs on waiting for device.

```
fastboot oem unlock
```

I have tried [Having issues seeing GLASS in Fastboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17519865/having-issues-seeing-glass-in-fastboot) using the manual reboot. I also tried factory reset on the device. Glass is using XE11. Does it have to do with the firmware change? The glass that I am using is from the latest Glass giveaway. Does fastboot use a seperate USB driver than adb?

Thank you for any leads

Comment: What OS are you using to do this? That will effect how well it works and some of the exact ways that the commands are entered.