# Can't root Google Glass XE19.1

Tags: root, google-glass

I want root Google Glss device XE19.1. All instruction i take from: https://developers.google.com/glass/tools-downloads/system

```
$ adb reboot bootloader  
$ fastboot devices # - give empty line...
```

$adb devices #show my device. Also a see my device in DDMS(Eclipse). My USB driver

```
#86
;GoogleGlass
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E11&REV_0216
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E11&MI_01
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_9001&REV_0216
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_9001&MI_01
%SingleBootLoaderInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_9001

#64
;GoogleGlass
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E11&REV_0216
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E11&MI_01
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_9001&REV_0216
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_9001&MI_01
%SingleBootLoaderInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_9001
```

What's trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm find solution - on Windows 7 this listing drivers for fastboot works, but on windows 8.1 don't work. I'm get root on PC with Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

If you can see your device in ADB but not in fastboot, then you're presumably *not* in fastboot mode.

It's easy to test: fastboot mode is indicated on Glass by the white LED flashing on briefly every few seconds.

**First thing to try** (note the extra hyphen): `adb reboot-bootloader`

If still no joy, try **entering fastboot manually** via recovery:

1. Turn Glass off
2. Hold down camera button
3. Briefly hold down power button
4. As soon as white LED is lit, release power button.
5. After 5 seconds, release camera button

... You will see a recovery menu on the Glass screen, giving an option to enter fastboot mode.

Finally, a couple of things to bear in mind. While plugged into my colleague's computer, Glass absolutely **will not enter fastboot mode** -- it will always reboot into the main image. We have no idea why. Second, you're on windows but for anyone else on OSX, **flashing to Glass is broken on OSX** at time of writing, so rooting must be done on a PC.

*Edit: found an older but similar question here:*
[Having issues seeing GLASS in Fastboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17519865/having-issues-seeing-glass-in-fastboot)